# Adding a tree view container to sidebar

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, treeview, vscode-extensions

Hey guys I'm making a JavaScript extension and I'm trying to add a tree view container
now I've looked in the docs but its all in typescript , I've also looked online and its also all
in typescript does this mean that I can only do this via a typescript extension ?

this is what I'm trying to recreate in my JavaScript extension any help is awesome

[this is what im trying to replicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgpVC.png)

Comment: take the TS example compile it and look at the JavaScript generated, I have written a JS only TreeView, VSC only understands JS

Comment: ahhh okay awesome thanks for the help was scratching my head on this one XD

Comment: your image is for a ViewContainer but the principle is the same